# Examples of rings by their relation to projective coverings

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, projective-module, algebras

A projective covering of an $R$-module $M$ is an epimorphism $\pi:P\rightarrow M$ s.t. $P$ is a projective $R$-module and $\textrm{Ker}(\pi)$ is co-essential in $P.$ The existence theorem for projective coverings says: every module over a finite-dimensional algebra has got a projective covering, i.e. any finite-dimensional algebra is (left and right) perfect.

I wonder if there are rings $R$ s.t.

- Only projective (free) $R$-modules has got projective coverings?
- Every finitely generated left $R$-module has got a projective covering but there is a left module which hasn't got?
- $R$ is left perfect but not right perfect?

(I  know that, for instance, every module over a field is projective, so in this case only projective modules has got projective coverings; but this is not the example I expect :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I wonder if there are rings  s.t. only projective (free) -modules has got projective coverings?

Yes, there's an elementary theorem that over any semiprimitive ring, the only modules with projective covers are already projective. See T.Y. Lam's *First course in noncommutative rings* example 5 p 361.

- Every finitely generated left -module has got a projective covering but there is a left module which hasn't got?

Yeah, that is the difference between a semiperfect ring and a left perfect ring.  Here's [the DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=25&L=82l).  For posterity, such an example is $k[[x]]$ where $k$ is a field.

- is left perfect but not right perfect?

Yes, it is known to be an asymmetric condition.  [DaRT query](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=82r&L=82l).  Specifically if you take the subset of $M_\mathbb N(F)$ for a field $F$ of infinite matrices which only have finitely many nonzero entries above the diagonal, and generate the subring generated by those elements and the identity matrix, you get a left-not-right perfect ring.